# Changes in Transformer

Tags: transformer

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEGAdU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What happens when we will remove the busbar which is joined down there marked in the image ?          And we **will also not change the Star configuration to delta configuration**. We will keep all the coils unconnected. i.e. we would just remove the busbar which is marked the, will the transformer work. If yes, `then would there be any change in the voltage or current level.`

[image]

Comment: Make an accurate drawing

Comment: It seems each coil has a tap near the 1st winding shared by the busbar for Neutral but the black wire Neutral contact is hidden from view.  The taps are unconnected and might be used for current monitoring on each phase.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 The white coloured pipe is connected so to cool down the coil by flowing water.  this is the transformer of the rectifier which converts the 415V 200Amp ac to 80V 1000amp dc. Or you were talking about the other tap

Comment: @SmitFefar, I'm not used with this type of transformer, but it is very hard to identify exactly what is the connections. If you simple remove the neutral connection bar, I believe it will work as 'single phase' on each of the phases. Maybe, if the loads are symmetrical, it will still work properly, but of course it is not recommended.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

> ... will the transformer work?

No.

- Voltage between outputs will be zero.
- Current will be zero.

You will have three open-circuit secondary windings.